# Equivalent of `info proc mappings` for GDB/MI

Tags: gdb, gdbserver, mi

I'm aware of `-file-list-exec-sections`, but it seems to be unimplemented in GDB 10.2 (the current as of this time). I wanted a GDB/MI command instead of `info proc mappings` as I wanted a easier way to parse the results, and also because I was wondering if there any alternatives to the `-file-list-exec-sections` command as it seems like it vanished.

Comment: The `info proc mappings` appears to work fine in GDB/MI. Are you asking for an equivalent _but different_ command?

Comment: `info proc mappings` gives its output in stream records (~"    0x40000   0x50000 0x10000 0x0 someprogram\n") which may get mixed up with other output since the records do not carry any leading token (e.g. `5-some-mi-cmd` will output `5^done,result=...`, but `5info proc mapping` will give output as stream records without any leading number, but will end with a `5^done`). Which is why I was wondering is there is any GDB/MI command that does the same as `info proc mappings`.

Answer (score 0):

Use interpreter directive

```
-interpreter-exec console "info proc mappings "
```

you will get parsable output (a bit uglier than mi interpreter but does the job )

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.